# When will I be able to purchase the car dealership in San Fierro in GTA: San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I know its an old game, but when I played it first buying houses was a matter as I had no money. But now that I know a cheat, I can have money to make the purchases. But in the game there is an house, which is blue in color I mean the house icon that is blue and keeps telling me that this house cannot be purchased right now.

How can I get that house to be green? Its a car garage I guess and its infront of the home that's in Dowerty (the construction thing area, remember? where we burry the man in cement).

I am sure there might be a way or a mission by which we can enable that, but I cannot figure it out, I killed Smoke in the last mission but still that house was Blue.

Comment: Can you be more specific? In particular, screenshots of the house and its location on the map would help. Also, instead of saying who you've killed (dude, spoilers!), give the name of the last story mission you've completed (which is easier for people to search for anyways). Off the top of my head, some safehouses are unlocked by completing side missions, so try that first.

Comment: Oh, ok next time when I play the game in just a few moments i will take the screenshots :) and ummm I dont remember the last mission as I still have to reach to that level this time.

Comment: @ToxicFrog - He's talking about the car dealership in San Fierro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To unlock "Wang Cars" -the car dealership in Doherty- & the associated missions from Caesar, you must first complete all driving school tests, and the '[Yay Ka-Boom-Boom](http://gta.wikia.com/Yay_Ka-Boom-Boom)' mission (possible spoilers, click at your own risk).

Jethro will call, and tell you the place has gone on sale. After purchasing it, you will receive missions from Caesar to 'stock up' the showroom.

Source: [GTA Wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/Wang_Cars)

Comment: Yeah man, you rock! Thats what I was talking about :) And yeah, I have done that mission I am just trying to get more hoods now to go to that smoke level! :) Thanks for this info, I was just trying to get rid of that driving level hehehe will do now :) Thanks Robotnik..